# Github Actions Node Workflow deploy on aws instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, github-actions, workflow

I want to create an AWS instance, which deploys my project from GitHub with Nginx. I'm doing this whole process with GitHub Actions. This worked, but I found out that the token expires every 60 minutes. So I added a Secret Variable in Github and added it to the Workflow file:

```yaml
token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN_NAME }}
```

Now the workflow isn't working properly. It is running and showing this for hours:

```
Requested labels: self-hosted
Job defined at: yuuval/react-deploy-aws/.github/workflows/node.js.yml@refs/heads/master
Waiting for a runner to pick up this job...
```

This happened after I configured the token.
I need this token to run a terraform file with its cloud-init, without changing any command.

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

   jobs:
     build: runs-on: self-hosted

strategy:
  matrix:
    node-version: [16.x]
    # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
  uses: actions/setup-node@v3
  with:
    node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    cache: 'npm'
    token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN_NAME }}
- run: npm ci
- run: npm run build --if-present
```

Comment: Isn't it related to the self-hosted runner and not that token? The step with that `token` comes after `checkout` so at least it should work to that point if that's the issue. I believe this is the path to your workflow i.e. `yuuval/react-deploy-aws/.github/workflows/node.js.yml`, right?

Comment: yes that's the path. the self-hosted works for sure. And what do you mean with comes after the checkout? Where should the token be set otherwise?

Comment: After looking at this wait message "**Waiting for a runner to pick up this job...**" and your description that it's like for hours, it looks like the runner is experiencing a high load and that's why it's not responsive. And, so for `token`, it's part of a step after checkout. For this to be effective, at least the runner should pick the job first. IIUC, both are two different issues: 1) the runner is not picking up the job, and 2) if it picks up the job, it fails due to `token`.

Comment: I think the problem is the token. If i remove it and take the old version, where the token is not set, the runner is picking the job immediately.

Comment: That is strange. You might want to [open an issue](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/new/choose) on the repo to report this behavior. Also, the indentation of the YAML in the question looks a bit. You need to verify and revise that also.

Comment: if i set the token to a fix value, the problem stays. Weird